# Get the mtime of a symlink and not its target in Python

Tags: python, symlink, filemtime

In Python (and Python2) on macOS, when I use

```
os.path.getmtime('/path/to/a/symlink')
```

I get the modification time of the symlink's *target*. - How do I get instead the modification time of the symlink itself?

Comment: tried `os.stat(filename)`?

Comment: Makes sense. Great find.  @LeiYang would you like to make it into a proper answer?

Comment: i'm afraid i don't understand the internal difference either.

Comment: Is the os.path.getmtime() with symlink behavior documented anywhere? I need the current behavior and my code will stop working if a future python release changes os.path.getmtime() to return the mtime of the symlink itself.

Comment: @Steve The doco of [getmtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) does _not_ go into detail, but the doco for other functions in `os.path` gives hints. E.g. for [isfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) it says: "Return True if path is an existing regular file. **This follows symbolic links, so both islink() and isfile() can be true for the same path.**" So I don't think you need to worry the behaviour of getmtime will change.

Answer (score 1):

As @LeiYang hinted in a comment, use [`os.lstat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.lstat) instead.

However, the result is not an `mtime` float, but rather a [`stat_result`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) structure.

How to extract the mtime information see [stat — Interpreting stat() results](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stat.html) in the Python documentation.